# Github actions, concurrent jobs after common setup job

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a project with multiple packages, and I'm trying to write a testing workflow for it.

I'm trying to create an action that does some common setup (like installing dependencies and compiling the app), and then, split into multiple jobs with [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs), to run the tests on each package.

I have a working "setup" job, and I can get the "test" job running in parallel with matrix, but I can't get the "test" job to run on the same environment as the "setup" job. so i need to reinstall and rebuild all the dependencies in each "test" job run.

Comment: Could you share your workflow file in the question please?

Comment: Anyway, you can't share those setups between jobs because each Github runner uses a different host, and will need to perform those steps to configure the environment according to your context. To avoid this problem, you can use a `self-hosted` runner or a `docker image`, with all the setup configurations you need (it might even be faster / optimized compare to what you're using now depending on the amount of setup steps you have).